# View raw circuit board production files

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, gcode

After ordering some PCBs involving fairly complex milling patterns from a Chinese supplier, I was given the production files and asked to verify that they are correct. However, I'm not sure what software I might use for this purpose, or even what format the data is in. I was originally given a RAR archive containing several sub-archives, that when extracted, produced the below file tree.

After opening the files in the root `ok` folder I discovered that many of them seemed to be gcode, but the coordinates seemed to be really large and the units seemed to not be in either mm or inches. I've linked the `bl` gcode file at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iyDGTMyRQusyLc0Y1U8_9xC5eDlBLGwC/view?usp=sharing.

Any thoughts on what this file format is, and how I might verify its correctness?

```
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is 8A07-1A4D
C:.
|   output.txt
|   
\---ok
    |   bl
    |   bo
    |   bs
    |   ck
    |   drl
    |   ko
    |   tl
    |   ts
    |   
    \---221155.tgz
        \---221155.tar
            +---ext
            +---flows
            +---fonts
            |       standard
            |       
            +---fonts_ex
            |   \---shx
            +---forms
            +---input
            +---matrix
            |       .matrix.sum
            |       matrix
            |       
            +---misc
            |       .attrlist.sum
            |       .info.sum
            |       .userattr.sum
            |       attrlist
            |       info
            |       job_name
            |       last_save
            |       userattr
            |       
            +---output
            +---stackups
            +---steps
            |   +---edit
            |   |   |   .attrlist.sum
            |   |   |   .profile.sum
            |   |   |   .stephdr.sum
            |   |   |   attrlist
            |   |   |   profile
            |   |   |   stephdr
            |   |   |   
            |   |   \---layers
            |   |       +---bl
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features.Z
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---bl+1
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---bo
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---bo+1
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---bs
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features.Z
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---bs+1
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---ck
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---drl
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       .tools.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features
            |   |       |       tools
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---ko
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       .tools.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features.Z
            |   |       |       tools
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---ko+1
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       .tools.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features.Z
            |   |       |       tools
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---tl
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features.Z
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---tl+1
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features
            |   |       |       
            |   |       +---ts
            |   |       |       .attrlist.sum
            |   |       |       .features.sum
            |   |       |       attrlist
            |   |       |       features.Z
            |   |       |       
            |   |       \---ts+1
            |   |               .attrlist.sum
            |   |               .features.sum
            |   |               attrlist
            |   |               features
            |   |               
            |   \---orig
            |       |   .attrlist.sum
            |       |   .profile.sum
            |       |   .stephdr.sum
            |       |   attrlist
            |       |   profile
            |       |   stephdr
            |       |   
            |       \---layers
            |           +---bl
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features
            |           |       
            |           +---bl+1
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features
            |           |       
            |           +---bo
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features
            |           |       
            |           +---bo+1
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features
            |           |       
            |           +---bs
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features
            |           |       
            |           +---bs+1
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features
            |           |       
            |           +---ck
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features
            |           |       
            |           +---drl
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       .tools.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features
            |           |       tools
            |           |       
            |           +---ko
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       .tools.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features.Z
            |           |       tools
            |           |       
            |           +---ko+1
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       .tools.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features.Z
            |           |       tools
            |           |       
            |           +---tl
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features
            |           |       
            |           +---tl+1
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features
            |           |       
            |           +---ts
            |           |       .attrlist.sum
            |           |       .features.sum
            |           |       attrlist
            |           |       features
            |           |       
            |           \---ts+1
            |                   .attrlist.sum
            |                   .features.sum
            |                   attrlist
            |                   features
            |                   
            +---symbols
            +---user
            |   \---input_reports
            |           07Apr20.193936
            |           
            +---wheels
            \---whltemps
```

Comment: Maybe the units are mils. 1 mil is 0.001 inches. A mili-inch. bl is bottom layer. bo is bottom overlay (aka silkscreen). bs is bottom solder (solder mask).  tl is top layer. ts is top solder. Not sure about ko and ck. drl is something related to drill. You need a gerber viewer to view the files. I usually use ViewMate gerber viewer which is a free download from Pentalogix.

Comment: What files did you send to the board house? Usually I send them gerbers and a fab drawing.

Comment: You ordered PCB...millings? What? Why? Not etching?

Comment: @mkeith I sent them Gerbers and a fab drawing as well, but my copper layer has 30+ polygons with cutouts and they weren't sure if it was rendering properly, despite the fact that the Gerber looked fine on my machine. I agree the units are probably mils (it's a circuit board after all), but I don't know any gcode viewer that supports mils. However, this archive doesn't look like a Gerber (the files inside are gcode), so a standard Gerber viewer wouldn't work.

Comment: @DKNguyen The PCB also has top and bottom copper layers, silkscreen, etc. It's just that the profile is really irregular and the board has 30+ oddly shaped holes.

Comment: When you said they were g codes I thought you just didn't know the difference between g codes and gerbers. Gerber files are also text files and they resemble g codes. Don't really know what to tell you. Ask them to send a screen shot? 30+ polygons does not sound complex to me.

Comment: All 30+ polygons were cutouts made from an imported DXF, which I had to write my own Python script to do. @mkeith Here's a link to the [bl file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iyDGTMyRQusyLc0Y1U8_9xC5eDlBLGwC/view?usp=sharing) in case you want to verify it yourself. The PCB is about 2" by 3" in size, so the numbers on this gcode seem too large to even be in mils.

Comment: What you describe does not sound overly complex at all. Board outlines are often cut with a router bit and they can be unbelievably complex at times. Usually I specifiy the board outline as a dedicated gerber layer labeled "board outline".  Gerber dimensions may omit decimal points. If I remember right, the location of the decimal point is specified once at the beginning for all coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like a standard [Gerber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerber_format) files: bl - Bottom Layer, bo - Bottom Overlay, bs - Bottom Silkscreen etc.

You can view it in any Gerber file viewer like: [Gerbv](http://gerbv.sourceforge.net/), [GerbView](https://www.kicad.org/) (from KiCAD) or other.

Also you can view it in 3D using [ZofzPCB](https://www.zofzpcb.com/).

[image]

Comment: Huh alright, I guess I don't know what Gerber files look like. Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI I also opened the file with viewmate and it looked just like this image. I also read a little bit of the gerber specification. Units can be either inches or mm but the decimal place is omitted. There is a format specifier that tells how to interpret the decimal place (basically, how many digits are after the decimal place). Gerbers are very similar to G codes. Maybe the same. It is all about loading an aperture (like loading a tool) then moving around with it similar to a milling operation.